# Multivariable Calculus - Finding the flux across a vector field out of a hemisphere

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

[Past Paper Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD5K7.png)

I had an exam today and this old past paper question came up again that I had previously tried. I followed the hints and got an answer of $4π$, with the flux across v out of D being $4π$ and the triple integral over the divergence of v (by the divergence theorem) $8π$, hence the final answer being 8 π - 4 π = 4 π again by the divergence theorem. Is this the correct answer?

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For future reference, it would be better just to type out *both* the original question *and* at least some of the details of your solution. As it stands, I know *one* mistake that you made but not the others.

Answer (score 2):

The flux across $D$ is $-4\pi$ (remember that the normal points downward when you think of $D$ as part of the boundary of $\Omega$). The triple integral of divergence over $\Omega$ is $3\cdot 16\pi/3 = 16\pi$. Thus, the flux across $S$ is $16\pi - (-4\pi) = 20\pi$. (Incidentally, this checks with a direct surface integral computation.)